# JSTL For Each Arraylist of Classes

Tags: jsp, aem

Using Adobe CQ 5.5 and JSP for a component object. Having some trouble to return results in JSTL.

I have an array of a custom class.

```
private static class Asset {

   private String displayname;

   public Asset(){
   }

   public String getDisplayName() {
      return displayname;
   }

   public void setDisplayName(String displayname) {
       this.displayname = displayname;
   }

}
```

This fragment works, but I want to use JSTL

```
  for (int i = 0; i < assets.size(); i++) {
      Asset c = assets.get(i);                        
      out.println(c.displayname + "<BR>");    
  }
```

This is what I want to do:

```
 request.setAttribute("assetList",assets);
%>

<c:forEach items="${assetList}" var="item" varStatus="status">
   <p>Title:</p> 
   ${item.displayname}
</c:forEach>
```

The JSTL does return 4 items like the working example, however as soon as I add in the `${item.displayname}`, I get an error.

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'displayname' not found on type org.apache.jsp.apps.pnc_002dideas.components.homepage.slider.slider_jsp$Asset
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:193)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:170)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:279)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:60)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:53)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:97)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.jsp.apps.dideas.components.homepage.slider.slider_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(slider_jsp.java:576)
    at org.apache.jsp.apps.pnc_002dideas.components.homepage.slider.slider_jsp._jspService(slider_jsp.java:372)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:497)
```

Comment: The problem is probably caused by the fact that the class is private. Why in hell are you defining classes and using Java code in JSPs?

Comment: I changed it from private to public... I am still getting that error.   Unfortunately that's my level of access.

Comment: because you are using wrong  naming convention  'displayname' you should use it as displayName.

Answer (score 5):

When using JSTL, the property names are resolved based on the getter method names and not the private field names.

Hence when you used `${item.displayname}`, it would be searching for the method `getDisplayname()` instead of `getDisplayName()`.

Either change your JSTL as shown below

```
<c:forEach items="${assetList}" var="item" varStatus="status">
   <p>Title:</p> 
   ${item.displayName}
</c:forEach>
```

or change your getter method in the bean as shown below to get it working.

```
   public String getDisplayname() {
      return displayname;
   }
```

Please do not change both.